# How Do I see hidden folders on Android?

Tags: file-management, hidden

This always happens to me. Someone tells me to access some folder on Android (in this case `/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.lmt/`) and I can't find it. I'm using the "File Manager" app and asking it to show hidden files and folders but I still can't find the folder. This happens a lot.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Why not try other apps like [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer), [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) or [Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.explorer)? They have options to show hidden files.

Comment: @k1chy I think you can post that as an answer.:)

Comment: What folder you don't find? `sdcard`? `Android`? `data`? `com.android.lmt`? You also need root to browse `/sdcard/Android/data`.

Answer (score 18):

First, you should be aware of the difference between "hidden folders" and "inaccessible folders":

- hidden folders: names start with a dot, e.g. `/sdcard/.android_secure`. These files you can see enabling the "hidden files" option in file explorers.
- inaccessible folders: folders you won't see due to lacking permissions, e.g. those in `/data`. To protect your apps' data, those folders belong to the corresponding application, and are only accessible by the app (in the context of [file-permissions](/questions/tagged/file-permissions); please see [the tag's wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-permissions/info) for closer information on those). To make those visible, you need root access on your device, and a file explorer supporting that (e.g. [ES File Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.estrongs.android.pop))

So while you were asking for the former ("hidden folders"), you were really referring to the latter: `data/com.android.lmt/` belongs to the *LMT launcher*.

Comment: the weird thing is that I have LMT installed but as you can see on the screenshot, the folder isn't showing up where it was supposed to be, t least where the XDA thread of the app says it should be. I've edited my question so you can see the screenshot

Comment: I bet the app is storing its data on `/data/com.android.lmt`, i.e. on internal storage. Only few app do so exclusively on SDCard, which is mostly used for "larger amounts of data" only. So the problem is not my description being wrong, but the folder not being there.

Comment: _"inaccessible folders: folders you won't see due to lacking permissions, e.g. those in /data."_ what about in Android Device Monitor when I am debugging an app I'm working on? Can I see the files now only because this is a debug build? Will a release version of the app keep these same files hidden?

Comment: To my understanding, yes. That's what the debug flag is for: to "debug" the app's internal working.

Answer (score 6):

Why not try other apps like [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer), [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) or [Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.explorer)?

They have options to show hidden files.

Comment: ES worked great to find `/sdcard/.android_secure` and delete it since it was zero bytes, which eliminated an error doing a backup

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro).

> **You can't find your hidden folders or files?**
>
> ASTRO FM is very robust and due to user requests, ASTRO added the
>   ability to override "global settings" with "directory specific
>   settings".
>
> First, go to Look and Feel under Preferences (menu, more, preferences,
>   look and feel).  Click on Show Hidden Files.  If this doesn't work, it
>   is because the directory that you have created some directory specific
>   settings on the directory you are in.
>
> You can either:
>
> a) go back to Look & Feel and click Reset Directories which will wipe
>   out any directory specific settings, or
>
> b) go to the directory your hidden files are in (probably your SD Card
>   directory) and click View, Set Directory Options, and click Show
>   Hidden Files in that directory.

Taken from [here](http://support.metago.net/entries/20414701-Cannot-see-Hidden-Files-or-Hidden-Folders)

Comment: I can confirm that the following worked just now to show my hidden ".Temp" folder on the internal sdcard: Settings icon -> Appearance -> Show hidden files -> check. Then, click "Clear" next to "Clear custom directory settings". Then, went back twice and the hidden ".Temp" folder was shown along with other hidden folders.